# How to create a line renderer with end point as the mouse position, but facing only one direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line

I have two objects with a line going from one to the other, like this:

[image]

I want to create another line with a starting point one of the objects and an end point the mouse position, however still facing the second object, which will look like the first line is filling up to where the mouse is, like this:

[image]

There is no way (as far as I know) to set a direction of a line renderer in Unity, so how can I achieve this?

Code for connecting the shapes:

```
 public void AddShape(GameObject shape) {
    selectedShape = shape;
    selectedShapeComp = shape.GetComponent<Shape>();

    if (!selectedShapes.Contains(selectedShape) && (selectedShapes.Count == 0 || selectedShape.CompareTag(selectedShapes[0].tag))) {
        currentAdjacentShapes = selectedShapeComp.GetAdjacentShapes();

        if (selectedShapes.Count == 0 && !selectedShapeComp.key) return; //If it's first and not a key, don't add it
        if (selectedShapes.Count == 0 && selectedShapeComp.key) activeKeys++; //If it's first and is a key, continue

        FindCurrentlyAdjacentShapes();

        if (currentAdjacentShapes != null && !currentAdjacentShapes.Contains(selectedShape)) return; //If it's not adjacent to previous shape, don't add it

        selectedShapes.Add(selectedShape);
        MarkShape();

        if (selectedShapes.Count > 1 && selectedShapeComp.key) MarkLeftOutShapes();

        SelectionLineSpawner.instance.SpawnLine();
    }

    ClearShapesAhead();
    CalculateSelectedShapesAmount();
}

private void RemoveShape(int index) {
    UnmarkShape(selectedShapes[index]);
    selectedShapes.RemoveAt(index);
}

private void ClearShapesAhead() {
    for (int i = selectedShapes.Count; i > selectedShapeComp.selectedPos; i--) {
        RemoveShape(i - 1);
    }
}

private void FindCurrentlyAdjacentShapes() {
    if (selectedShapes.Count > 1) {
        currentAdjacentShapes = selectedShapes[selectedShapes.Count - 1].GetComponent<Shape>().GetAdjacentShapes();
    }
}

private void MarkLeftOutShapes() {
    var shapes = new List<GameObject>();

    switch (selectedShape.tag) {
        case "Diamond":
            shapes = LevelLoader.instance.currentLevel.GetAllDiamonds();
            break;
        case "Triangle":
            shapes = LevelLoader.instance.currentLevel.GetAllTriangles();
            break;
    }

    foreach (var shape in shapes) {
        if (!selectedShapes.Contains(shape)) {
            Debug.Log("Not selected: " + shape.name);
        }
    }
}

private void MarkShape() {
    selectedShape.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
    selectedShape.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("select");
    selectedShapeComp.selected = true;
    selectedShapeComp.selectedPos = selectedShapes.Count;
}

private void UnmarkShape(GameObject shape) {
    var shapeComp = shape.GetComponent<Shape>();
    shapeComp.selected = true;
    shapeComp.selectedPos = 0;
    shape.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
}

private void CalculateSelectedShapesAmount() {
    switch (selectedShape.tag) {
        case "Diamond":
            LevelLoader.instance.currentLevel.selectedDiamonds = selectedShapes.Count;
            break;
        case "Triangle":
            LevelLoader.instance.currentLevel.selectedTriangles = selectedShapes.Count;
            break;
    }
}

private void DrawLines() {
    foreach (var shape in LevelLoader.instance.currentLevel.GetAllShapes()) {
        var adjacentShapes = shape.GetComponent<Shape>().GetAdjacentShapes();

        foreach (var adjacentShape in adjacentShapes) {
            var lineClone = Instantiate(line);
            lineClone.transform.parent = shape.transform;
            var lineComp = lineClone.GetComponent<Line>();

            foreach (Transform child in adjacentShape.transform) {
                if (child.CompareTag("Line"))
                    if (child.GetComponent<Line>().origin != adjacentShape)
                        lineComp.DrawLine(shape, adjacentShape);
            }

            if (!lineComp.IsDrawn())
                Destroy(lineClone);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can calculate direction by using last position in line renderer positions and mouse position. And then add a new position by adding an offset. I didnt get one thing here, if the line is filling the other line why do you need any direction at all?

Comment: @UmairM Because the line that fills the other line needs to be in the same place, but draw itself using the mouse

Comment: And what happens when the mouse pos is not not on the line? Is this drawing top down view or is the camera facing the Z axis? It would make sense to post a code of what you currently have.

Comment: @Programmer There is no code to it yet. The white lines are automatically generated to connect to the nearest object. The "highlight" lines need to stick to the closest white line and extend with the mouse/touch movement. For example, if I want to connect the blue shape with the green shape and I move my mouse towards it, the blue line should follow my mouse, while still staying on top of the white line.

Comment: Ok. You should ask the question again when you have a code that connects from one object to another then tell us where you are stuck. I will be able to answer. Right now, proving an answer is like writing all the code. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer I thought you meant code for the selection lines, sorry. I do have the code for the shape selection, wrote it in my post.

Comment: Instead of that thing you do above, why don't you use a ProgressBar? You can use EditorGUI's, create your own with Texture2D, download something free from Asset Store, etc. You place it wherever you want between the two objects, and fill up the "progress" based on mouse distance/position/whatever you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are steps to implement what you want:

- Find the mouse's world position on plane defined by the two objects and camera,
- Find the closest point from that position to the line between the two objects,
- Draw the line from the start object to that closest point

Here is a code that may guide you:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Question : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 startPosition = Vector3.left * 5;
    public Vector3 endPosition = Vector3.right * 5;

    void OnDrawGizmos() {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawCube(startPosition, Vector3.one);
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(endPosition, 1);

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(startPosition, endPosition);

        var mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        var mousePos = mouseRay.GetPoint(Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        var pointOnLine = ClosestPointOnLine(startPosition, endPosition, mousePos, true);

        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(startPosition, pointOnLine);
    }

    /// <summary> Returns the point nearest point to the [point] on the line given by start and end points, [lineStart] and [lineEnd]</summary>
    /// <param name="clampLine"> If true, the returned point will be on the line segment, rather than the line. </param>
    public static Vector3 ClosestPointOnLine(Vector3 lineStart, Vector3 lineEnd, Vector3 point, bool clampLine = false) {
        var dif = lineEnd - lineStart;
        var direction = Vector3.Normalize(dif);
        float closestPoint = Vector3.Dot((point - lineStart), direction) / dif.magnitude;
        if (clampLine)
            closestPoint = Mathf.Clamp(closestPoint, 0, 1);
        return lineStart + (closestPoint * dif);
    }
}
```

To test this code, just paste it into a file, create a game object in the scene and add this component to it. This only works with an orthographic camera.

The `ClosestPointOnLine` method is one that may help you in many situations so I keep it documented.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it soon and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you will have to achieve this by using mathematics and more precisely [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection). Following [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/Projection_and_rejection.png) you can can your **b** vector easily since it's your line going from one object to another, you can get your **a** vector with something like `new Vector3(Input.mouse.position - basePositionOfYourLine)` and then compute the **a1** vector.